# Timing Problem with SetState and PreviousState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and having an issue possibly with threading.

I have a parent class that creates a series of buttons (mapped via an array).

The parent class adds the buttons to the array on a timer.  Whereas the child class has an onclick attribute that calls the parent method to remove the buttons.

It appears the remove button doesn't always remove the right button.  I'm using the  setState with previousState functionality.  I'd like to know what I'm doing incorrectly.

I'll show the parent and child classes.  I've tried not to include all the import and other classes to simplify the problem, sorry that the code is still long.

Parent:

```
class PanelDiv extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [0] };
    this.addChild = this.addChild.bind(this);
    this.buttonClickHandler = this.buttonClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="DivBackground"
        onLoad={() => this.PanelLoaded()}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          backgroundImage: "url(" + BackgroundImage + ")",
          backgroundSize: "cover"
        }}
      >
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <NumberButton
            key={"Nb" + item.toString()}
            parentClickHandler={this.buttonClickHandler}
            id={"Nb" + item.toString()}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.addChild, Settings.COMPONENT_ADD_INTERVAL);
  }

  buttonClickHandler(clientId) {
    this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {
      var foundIndex = previousState.items.findIndex(function(element) {
        console.log(clientId);
        return element.toString() === clientId.substring(2);
      });

      previousState.items.splice(foundIndex, 1);
      return { items: previousState.items };
    });
  }

  addChild() {
    this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {
      return {
        items: previousState.items.concat([
          previousState.items[previousState.items.length - 1] + 1
        ])
      };
    });
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class NumberButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var varLeft = (0 + Math.random() * (100 - 0)).toString() + "%";
    var timeoutValue =
      Settings.BUTTON_SPEED_MIN +
      Math.random() * (Settings.BUTTON_SPEED_MAX - Settings.BUTTON_SPEED_MIN);
    var numberValue = Math.round(Math.random() * Settings.MAX_NUMBER);
    this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      clientId: props.id,
      wavePath: Waves[numberValue],
      left: varLeft,
      top: 0,
      counter: "Hello",
      timeoutValue: timeoutValue,
      numberValue: numberValue
    };
  }

  updateCount() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return { top: prevState.top + 1 };
    });
    setTimeout(() => this.updateCount(), this.state.timeoutValue);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateCount();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        id={this.state.clientId}
        onClick={() => this.buttonClicked()}
        style={{
          color: "white",
          fontSize: Settings.BUTTON_FONT_SIZE,
          fontFamily: "Verdana",
          border: "none",
          backgroundColor: "Transparent",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundImage: "url(" + CoconutImage + ")",
          position: "absolute",
          left: this.state.left,
          top: this.state.top,
          width: Settings.BUTTON_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT,
          height: Settings.BUTTON_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT
        }}
      >
        {this.state.numberValue}
      </button>
    );
  }

  buttonClicked() {
    var audio = new Audio(this.state.wavePath);
    audio.play();
    this.props.parentClickHandler(this.state.clientId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not mutate objects in state. You should return **new object** based on previous state.

```js
 
  buttonClickHandler(clientId) {
    this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => ({
      items: previousState.items.filter(element => (
        element.toString() !== clientId.substring(2))
      )
    }));
  }
```

Try this, probably will help.

Comment: It works more often than the other one, but still, sometimes I get the problem were more than one gets removed, just like with the other function...so similar concurrency problem

Comment: I figured it out...i sometimes have a key with nan in it...when the list is empty

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred due to a duplicate key problem with a value of NaN.

This was the fix:

```
  addChild() 
  {

    this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {

        if (previousState.items.length == 0)
          return {items:[0]};
        else
          return {items: previousState.items.concat([previousState.items[previousState.items.length-1]+1])};
    });
  }
```