# React Click To Unmount Component Message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting this message on unmounting a component:

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.
>       in NumberButton (at App.js:37)

I have a parent, with an array with a list of buttons.  The buttons each have an `onclick` that calls the parent which will remove the clicked button from the list.

The problem is that the function's purpose is a click to essentially destroy itself.  The way the method is done, it doesn't require an explicit bind that would require an unbind, so I wouldn't think there's a memory leak in the component.

Please advise why I'd be getting this message, what I can do, and if its a false positive message.

Parent Class:

```
class PanelDiv extends Component
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {items: [0]};
    this.addChild = this.addChild.bind(this);
    this.buttonClickHandler = this.buttonClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  render()
  {
    return (<div id="DivBackground" onLoad={() => this.PanelLoaded()} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundImage: "url(" + BackgroundImage + ")", backgroundSize: "cover"}}>
      {
          this.state.items.map((item) => (
            <NumberButton key={"Nb" + item.toString()} parentClickHandler={this.buttonClickHandler} id={"Nb" + item.toString()} />
          ))
      }
    </div>);
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    setInterval(this.addChild, Settings.COMPONENT_ADD_INTERVAL);
  }

  buttonClickHandler(clientId) {

    this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => ({
      items: previousState.items.filter(element => {

        return element.toString() !== clientId.substring(2)

      }
        //console.log("Matching Element: ")
      )
    }));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

  }

  addChild() 
  {

    this.setState((previousState, currentProps) => {

        if (previousState.items.length == 0)
          return {items:[0]};
        else
          return {items: previousState.items.concat([previousState.items[previousState.items.length-1]+1])};
    });
  }
}
```

Child Class:

```
class NumberButton extends Component
{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var varLeft = (0 + (Math.random() * (90-0))).toString() + '%';
    var timeoutValue = Settings.BUTTON_SPEED_MIN + (Math.random() * (Settings.BUTTON_SPEED_MAX-Settings.BUTTON_SPEED_MIN));
    var numberValue = Math.round(Math.random() * (Settings.MAX_NUMBER));


    this.state = { clientId: props.id, wavePath: Waves[numberValue], left: varLeft, top: 0, counter: "Hello", timeoutValue: timeoutValue, numberValue: numberValue };
  }


  updateCount() {

    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return { top: prevState.top + 1 }
    });
    setTimeout(()=> this.updateCount(), this.state.timeoutValue)

  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.updateCount();
    //this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <button id={this.state.clientId} onClick={() => this.buttonClicked()} style={{color: "white", fontSize: Settings.BUTTON_FONT_SIZE, fontFamily: "Verdana", border: "none", backgroundColor: "Transparent", backgroundSize: "cover", backgroundImage: "url(" + CoconutImage + ")", position: "absolute", left: this.state.left, top: this.state.top, width: Settings.BUTTON_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT, height: Settings.BUTTON_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT}}>
      {this.state.numberValue}
      </button>

    );
  }


  buttonClicked()
  {
    var audio = new Audio(this.state.wavePath);
    audio.play();
    this.props.parentClickHandler(this.state.clientId);
  }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488307/timing-problem-with-setstate-and-previousstate/52489148#52489148) was my original question for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do setTimeout or setInterval you make sure you clear them in componentWillUnMount life cycle method. Something like below

```
 componentDidMount() {
      this.addChildTimer = setInterval(this.addChild, Settings.COMPONENT_ADD_INTERVAL);
  }

  componentWillUnMount(){
      clearInterval(this.addChildTimer);
 }
```

> componentWillUnmount is meant to eliminate the interval that was set
>   earlier when it mounted

Like wise in your child component

```
 updateCount() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
     return { top: prevState.top + 1 }
 });
 this.updateCountTimer = setTimeout(()=> this.updateCount(), this.state.timeoutValue)
 }

 componentWillUnMount(){
   clearTimeout(this.updateCountTimer);
}
```

Note: Avoid doing setState inside setInterval

Comment: I'll review this in about 12 hours...looks promising though

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue in your code is caused by timers. You have setTimeout and setInterval in your code which will execute even after your component has unmounted. So the error should be more clear now (you can't set state for unmounted component).

Make the following changes to your code.

Parent Class

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.addChild, Settings.COMPONENT_ADD_INTERVAL);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
```

Child Class

```
this.updateCountTimout = setTimeout(()=> this.updateCount(), this.state.timeoutValue);


componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.updateCountTimout);
}
```